# Dockerized Spring Boot app can't get JDBC connection string on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, docker, heroku, jdbc

I'm trying to run the Dockerized Spring Boot application on Heroku. I use `dockerfile-maven` and plugin to create the app I use this commands

```
heroku apps:create my-app-name --buildpack heroku/java
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app my-app-name
```

Notice that I'm using `buildpack` here.

In `application.properties` I have such lines

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:some default jdbc connection string}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

How I understand if I set the `heroku/java` buildpack for the app the environment variables JDBC_DATABASE_URL should be created but in my case, I see the default connection string in logs. That's mean that  JDBC_DATABASE_URL is not set or not available. Why that's could happen?

Worth to mention that `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is available in the application.

Comment: What is this $JDBC_DATABASE_URL variable value ? Is this DB a separate container?

Comment: Here is detailed explanation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java

Comment: Simply speaking DATABASE_URL contains connection string which is not JDBC format. If you ran java app on Heroku it creates another env variable with JDBC connection string. But in case you deploy dockerized Java app it's not doing that. Only solution is to convert it with the tricky bash script)))

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski this question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522399/how-to-connect-to-heroku-postgres-using-docker-spring-boot-app