# How to connect to heroku postgres using docker spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, heroku

I am trying to connect to the heroku postgres database I provisioned (not a docker image), from a docker app I deployed to heroku. When I push to heroku the image builds fine but when the app starts I get an error. It seems like the JDBC_DATABASE_URL is not being injected into the docker container, but I don't know how to get it to work.

Here is my code:

heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY build/libs/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
CMD ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

application.properties

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
```

Comment: Maybe you should learn about Docker and Spring-Boot. By the way it's normal for you to get this  `RuntimeException`, the var named `{JDBC_DATABASE_URL}` is called but never created before.

Comment: Thank you, @Zorglube. Can you point me to a resource where I can learn how to create the variable so I don't get the exception?

Answer (score 3):

The `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` is set by the [Heroku buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). When you're using Docker, you don't get to use buildpacks. If you want to mimic what the buildpack does you can copy this [JDBC Profile script](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common/blob/master/opt/jdbc.sh) (but you'll have to update it manually if things ever change).

Comment: Thanks @codefinger! When using docker on heroku, is it better to use the postgres addon or a postgres docker image?

Comment: You can't run a postgres image on heroku

Comment: Does it mean that there are no correct way to run a spring boot app using a Postgres Heroku addons using docker on heroku?